# How can I secure my custom rest api endpoint or add under a already existing rest group

Tags: rest-api, authentication, endpoints

Creating a custom REST Endpoint I search a way to secure the route with JWT or integrate my endpoint under Woocommerce rest routes which already has an authentication logic.

The perfect solution for me would be the second option. Can somebody give me some hints how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you drop in a snippet of one endpoint you are trying to add??

Comment: I added a new question  which provides more details on what I have been trying https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341312/extend-woocommerce-rest-api-routes-fails?noredirect=1#comment501430_341312