# Extend Woocommerce rest api routes fails

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, rest-api, callbacks, customization

While I'm trying to extend Woocommerce Rest-API routes with a custom one I face the following problem. I have the following class which tries to hook inside Woocommerce API

```
class API_LOADER
{
public function init()
        {
            add_action( 'woocommerce_api_loaded', array( $this, 'load' ) );
        }
        public function load()
        {
            //This method will be not called
            require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'wc-api-custom.php';
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_api_classes', array( $this, 'register' ) );
        }
}
```

but `woocommerce_api_loaded` will not trigger any callback.

What I do wrong in this case

Comment: "will not trigger any callback" - you mean your load function is never called? It looks like the hook is only called from class-wc-legacy-api, so it's probably worth adding trace to that to make sure it's being loaded and that your requests are hitting handle_rest_api_requests there.

Comment: hi thanks for feedback, exactly my load function will not fire, how would I go on with your suggestion?

Comment: There are probably better ways to do this, but I normally add `error_log` calls to the plugin on a test instance and then watch the webserver's error log (or PHP's error log, depending on your setup) to see what's happening. I'd start by putting logs in the class WC_Legacy_API constructor, handle_rest_api_requirements (the 'parse_request' hook), and probably then trace out WC_API_REQUEST_VERSION to see which handle function it's calling.

Comment: Try dropping in `do_action( 'woocommerce_api_loaded' ); ` to make sure things are triggered. And back to Rup's point, it sounds like you might need to start tracing those calls. Lastly, authors of Woocommerce ask that you not use the same namespace, but rather your own name space. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/11945#issuecomment-248208687. If you use a separate name space, then it's relatively easy to tap into current_user_can() to tie back to Woocommerce functionality to secure your end points.

Comment: the point why I want to use the same namespace as woocoomerce is to guard the access to the route with same authentication method used by woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

What if in your `register_rest_route()` call you can pass it the *permission_callback* option:

```
'permission_callback' => function () {
  return current_user_can('customer');
  // OR
  return current_user_can('shop_manager');
}
```

That way you are sure that you are dealing with a logged in Woocommerce user??

These are the two roles that Woocommerce is adding to your site. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/roles-capabilities/

I know it's not answering your question directly, but I hope this helps! If I am way off, I can take the answer down.

Comment: thanks for feedback, but I think your workaround can not deal with remote requests. I mean I would like to request endpoints from remote server and able to use OAuth to authenticate against the rest-api and woocommerce already has a logic behind. But I appreciate your point with the permission callback if I do not find an appropriate way to integrate my route inside woocommerce this is the way to go

Comment: I am sure you've seen it, but there are a few options for external requests, here is a link with a few options that WP lays out. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins